# Efficiently convert numpy array of arrays to pandas series of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

How would I efficiently convert a numpy array of arrays into a list of arrays?  Ultimately, I want to make a pandas Series of arrays to be a columns in a dataframe. If there is a better way to go directly to, that would also be good.

The following reproducible code solves the issue with `list()` or `.tolist()`, but either is much too slow to implement on my actual data set. I am looking for something much faster.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7])])

s = pd.Series(a.tolist())

s = pd.Series(list(a))
```

This results in the shape going from `a.shape = (2,4)` to `s.values.shape = (2,)`.

Comment: Why not `pd.DataFrame(a)`?

Comment: `a` is 2d array, (2,4).  Not an array of arrays (unless you went to the extra work of constructing a (2,) shape object array first).  That should map on to a 4 column DataFrame.  Or do you really want a Series where each element is an array (and object dtype)?  I don't think that will be an `efficient` Series.  It isn't an efficient `array`.

Comment: @hpaulj - Yes I "want a Series where each element is an array."

Comment: @miradulo that results in a separate column for each element in the nested arrays.  I want the resulting data frame to have one column where each row has one of the nested arrays of `a`.

Comment: Do you know how to make a 1d  array that contains arrays?  object dtyoe?  Your example `a` doesn't qualify. Try varying the subarray length, or include a `None`

Comment: Which is too slow, `a.tolist()`,  or making the Series from that list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `a`:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7])])
   ...:
```

`a` is (2,4) numeric array; we could have just written `a = np.array([[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]])`.  Creating a (2,) array of arrays requires a different construction.

As others wrote, making a dataframe this is trivial:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(a)     # dtypes int64
Out[3]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6  7
```

But making a series from it raises an error:

```
In [4]: pd.Series(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Your question would have been clearer if it showed this error, and why then you tried the list inputs:

```
In [5]: pd.Series(a.tolist())
Out[5]: 
0    [0, 1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6, 7]
dtype: object
In [6]: pd.Series(list(a))
Out[6]: 
0    [0, 1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6, 7]
dtype: object
```

On the surface these are the same, but when we look at actual elements of the Series, we see that one contains lists, the other arrays.  That's because `tolist` and `list()` create different lists from the array.

```
In [8]: Out[5][0]
Out[8]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
In [9]: Out[6][0]
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

My experience is that `a.tolist()` is quite fast.  `list(a)` is equivalent to `[i for i in a]`; in effect it iterates on the first dimension of `a`, returning (in this case) a 1d array (row) each time.

---

Let's change `a` so it is a 1d object dtype array:

```
In [14]: a = np.array([np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7]), np.array([1]), None])
In [15]: a
Out[15]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([1]), None],
      dtype=object)
```

Now we can make a Series from it:

```
In [16]: pd.Series(a)
Out[16]: 
0    [0, 1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6, 7]
2             [1]
3            None
dtype: object
In [17]: Out[16][0]
Out[17]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

In fact we could make a series from a slice of `a`, the one containing just the original 2 rows:

```
In [18]: pd.Series(a[:2])
Out[18]: 
0    [0, 1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6, 7]
dtype: object
```

The tricks for constructing 1d object dtype arrays have been discussed in depth in other SO questions.

Beware that a Series like this does not behave like a multicolumn DataFrame.  I've seen attempts to write csv files, where elements like this get saved as quoted strings.

---

Lets compare some construction times:

Make larger arrays of the 2 types:

```
In [25]: a0 = np.ones([1000,4],int)
In [26]: a1 = np.empty(1000, object)
In [27]: a1[:] = [np.ones(4,int) for _ in range(1000)]
# a1[:] = list(a0)   # faster
```

First make a DataFrame:

```
In [28]: timeit pd.DataFrame(a0)
136 µs ± 919 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This is the same time as for `Out[3]`; apparently just the overhead of making a DataFrame with a 2d array (any size) as `values`.

Making a series as you did:

```
In [29]: timeit pd.Series(list(a0))
434 µs ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [30]: timeit pd.Series(a0.tolist())
315 µs ± 5.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

both of these are longer than for the small `a`, reflecting the iterative nature of the creation.

And with the 1d object array:

```
In [31]: timeit pd.Series(a1)
103 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This is the same as for the small 1d array.  As with `In[28]` I think there's just the overhead of creating a `Series` object, and then assigning it an unchanged values array.

Now constructing the `a1` array is slower.

An object array like `a1` is in many way just like a list - it contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory.  It can be useful if the elements differ in type (e.g. include strings or None), but computationally it is not the equivalent of a 2d array.

---

In sum, if the source array really is a 1d object dtype array, you can quickly create a `Series` from it.  If it is really a 2d array, you'll need, in some way or other, convert it to a list or 1d object array first.

Answer (score 1):

You can make DataFrame from dict of common length list or list of lists. In former case pandas convert keys as column name and list as column values, in latter case each list is considered as rows.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6,7])])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = a.tolist()
df
```

Output:

```
    a
0   [0, 1, 2, 3]
1   [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks @krishna, but I need each row of **one** column of the data frame to contain each sub-array of `a`.

Comment: @Clay row 1 should be [0,4] and row 2 [1,5]?

Comment: No, row 1 col 1 should be `array([0,1,2,3])`, row 2 col 1 should be `array([4,5,6,7])`.  If you can first create a data frame from `a`, then convert each row to an array in a new column without using a for loop, that should work.

Comment: that is exactly the solution I gave in the original question, but is way to slow for a large data set.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'a':a.tolist()})`?

Comment: Thanks @krishna, but that still uses `.tolist()` which is too slow for my actual use case.

Comment: Can I know the shape of your actual use case?